# rotating an arrow in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to rotate the arrow to any given angle. What i need to add/modify so that it can be rotated to any angle. Currently its on 180 degree.

```
function drawArrowAtAngle(cx,cy,angle,context){
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = '#aaa';
  context.moveTo(cx+25,cx-2);
  context.lineTo(cx-55,cx-2);
  context.lineTo(cx-58,cx);
  context.lineTo(cx-55,cx+2);
  context.lineTo(cx+25,cx+2);
  context.lineTo(cx+25,cx-2);  
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
  context.restore();

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want the center of rotation to be `(cx,cx)`, insert the following three lines after the `context.save();` statement.

```
  context.translate(cx,cx) ;
  context.rotate(angle) ;
  context.translate(-cx,-cx) ;
```

This will cause the arrow to be rotated clockwise by `angle` (in radians).

You use `(cx,cx)` in your code to anchor the arrow.  If you really mean `(cx,cy)`, then adjust the above snippet accordingly.